# Spring Boot profiles not active when set with maven plugin

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I'm trying to set spring profiles when starting Tomcat for integration tests in maven like this:

```
...
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>pre-integration-test</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>start</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <profiles>
            <profile>testProfile</profile>
          </profiles>
        </configuration>
...
```

The profile is definitely not active.

On the other hand the following does work and the requested profile is active:

```
<jvmArguments>-Dspring.profiles.active=testProfile</jvmArguments>
```

The problem here is that we can't stop the server, which is a problem when running automated integration tests.

I'm using spring boot "1.4.0.RELEASE".

My questions:
1. Why does the profile tag not work? (Bug?)
2. Why id the JMX bean not found when trying to shutdown the server in the "stop" goal? Does this something have to do with the forking because of the jvmArguments?

Answer (score 1):

I was ignoring the args in the main method. Passing them to the Spring application solved it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  SpringApplication.run(RunServer.class, args);
}
```